# Selecting array within array with hyphens in name PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to select a column within an array within an array in SQL, where the top level array has hyphens in the array. It looks something like this:

```
table: wi-die
  array: wi-d
    array: prod
      col: no
      col: desc
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT wi_die."wi-d.prod.no"
FROM "wi-die" wi_die

SELECT wi_die."wi-d"[17][1]
FROM "wi-die" wi_die

SELECT wi_die."wi-d"[17] AS wi_d_prod,
       wi_d_prod[1]
FROM "wi-die" wi_die
```

and a few others. I can't find information on this anywhere.

Comment: What does the table look like? The output of `\d "wi-die"` from inside `psql` would be a good starting point.